# How to create hierarchical view in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-java-api

I have company documents in a bucket. I want to make a view of the company tree using those documents. How to achieve this using couchbase.

I have checked this link
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/possible-to-query-for-hierarchical-data-across-documents/11432/5

But unable to figure it out, Do I need to go with map-reduce, or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: check this out https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-query-with-self-referencing-hierarchy/

Comment: What version are you running?